# Authentication for desktop apps like in electron using firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, electron

[image]

```js
gLoginBtn.onclick=(event)=>{
      let gEmail=document.getElementById('gEmail').value;
      let gPassword=document.getElementById('gPassword').value;
      var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
  provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly');                firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
              // The signed-in user info.
              var user = result.user;
              alert("Welcome "+user.displayName);
              console.log(user);
            }).catch(function(error) {
              var errorMessage = error.message;
              alert(errorMessage);
            });
    }
```

```html
<h1>AUTHENTICATION USING GOOGLE</h1>
  <div>
      <form action="###">
          <label for="googleEmail">Enter name</label> <input type="text" id="gEmail"/> <br> <br>
          <label for="googlePassword">Enter Password</label> <input type="password" id="gPassword"/> <br> <br>
          <input type="submit" id="gLoginBtn" value="Login With Google"/>
      </form>
  </div>
```

This code works fine in my web application but when i am running in electron using npm run electron then its giving error. What changes will i need to do so that, it started working in desktop app also. i tried searching find one link [enter link description here](https://auth0.com/authenticate/electron/firebase/)  but did not get much information.

Comment: Why do you ask for Google email and password in your app?

Comment: So, what will i do? , I want to authenticate using google's email id and password. This is what requirement.

Comment: ohh fine now i got yours point, but still question remains same, error is same. I don't need that it's already authenticated in popup window.

Comment: The reason why I ask is because it sounds like a phishing app. You are not supposed to ask a user to enter their OAuth provider's email/password directly on your site. That is the whole point of OAuth.

Comment: Have you found your way around this?